# i can't find a formula that verifies if something repeats on a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm doing a project in googlesheets and i need to use a formula that verifies if an input on a segment repeats in other segments on the same column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your inputs are A1:A8, starting with A1:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8, A1) = 1, "UNIQUE", "REPEATS")
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmhSA.png)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I searched on line, but didn't find it, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to list which values were repeated, you could do it as single formula using:

```
=filter(unique(A:A),countif(A:A,unique(A:A))>1)
```

[image]

If you just wanted to know if there were *any* repeats anywhere, then it would just be

```
=counta(A:A)<>countunique(A:A)
```

Or if you wanted to flag up each row to show whether it was repeated or not:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A<>"",countif(A:A,A:A)>1,))
```